# Why does this C program compile with no errors?

Tags: c, compilation

I have the two C files, `main.c` and `weird.c`:

```
// main.c    
int weird(int *);

int
main(void)
{
    int x, *y;

    y = (int *)7;
    x = weird(y);
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    return (0);
}

// weird.c

char *weird = "weird";
```

However, when I run the following:

```
clang -Wall -Wextra -c main.c
clang -Wall -Wextra -c weird.c
clang -o program main.o weird.o
```

I do not get any errors. Why is this? Shouldn't there at least be linking errors? Note that I am just talking about compiling the files — not running them. Running gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: No link occurs when you use the `-c` flag.

Comment: @paddy oops sorry, I left out a couple commands. Editing the question now!

Comment: The language-lawyer answer is that the standard does not require a diagnostic for this error. The practical answer is that C does not type-decorate symbols with external linkage, so the type mismatch goes undetected.

Comment: This is an argument for making use of headers to ensure that different parts of a program are coherent. If you never declare an external function in a source file but only in headers, and use the headers wherever the relevant symbol (in this case `weird`) is used or defined, then the code would not all compile. You could either have a function or a string, but not both. You'd have a header `weird.h` which either contains `extern char *weird;` or `extern int weird(int *p);` (but not both), and both `main.c` and `weird.c` would include the header, and only one of them would compile successfully.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so what could I add to these files to ensure that the error is detected and thrown when main.c is compiled?

Comment: `y = (int *)7;` causes undefined behaviour (unaligned pointer)

Comment: The main purpose of `.h`files in C is to properly announce the function signatures and other type definitions in your `.o` files to calling modules that will *link* to the module. You haven't used that feature at all.

Comment: I have rolled back the latest edit. It significantly changed the question and there have already been several answers posted which address the original code. If you want to ask about only the code in that edit, then post a new question.

Comment: Note that the new revision now has non-compilable C code for `weird.c`. (According to the revision, `weird.c` contains `char *weird = "weird";
printf(weird);` but you can't write function calls outside functions, and you need a header to declare the function.)  This will not compile without errors as claimed.  The code in `main.c` gets lots of warnings, too.

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 7):

#### Should there be a linker error?

The short answer to "Shouldn't there at least be linking errors?" is "There is no guarantee that there'll be a linking error".  The C standard doesn't mandate it.

As [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928315/why-does-this-c-program-compile-with-no-errors/36929908#comment61417341_36928315):

> The language-lawyer answer is that the standard does not require a diagnostic for this error. The practical answer is that C does not type-decorate symbols with external linkage, so the type mismatch goes undetected.

One of the reasons C++ has type-safe linkage is to avoid problems with code analogous to this (though the main reason is to allow for function name overloading — resolving this sort of problem is, perhaps, more a side-effect).

The C standard says:

> **§6.9 External definitions**
>
> ¶5 An *external definition* is an external declaration that is also a definition of a function
>   (other than an inline definition) or an object. If an identifier declared with external
>   linkage is used in an expression (other than as part of the operand of a `sizeof` or
>   `_Alignof` operator whose result is an integer constant), somewhere in the entire
>   program there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier; otherwise, there
>   shall be no more than one.
>
> **§5.1.1.1 Program structure**
>
> ¶1 A C program need not all be translated at the same time. The text of the program is kept in units called source files, (or preprocessing files) in this International Standard. A source file together with all the headers and source files included via the preprocessing directive `#include` is known as a preprocessing translation unit. After preprocessing, a preprocessing translation unit is called a translation unit. Previously translated translation units may be preserved individually or in libraries. The separate translation units of a program communicate by (for example) calls to functions whose identifiers have external linkage, manipulation of objects whose identifiers have external linkage, or manipulation of data files. Translation units may be separately translated and then later linked to produce an executable program.
>
> **5.1.1.2 Translation phases**
>
> 8. All external object and function references are resolved. Library components are linked to satisfy external references to functions and objects not defined in the current translation. All such translator output is collected into a program image which contains information needed for execution in its execution environment.

The linking is done based on the names of external definitions, not on the types of the objects identified by the name.  The onus is on the programmer to ensure that the type of the function or object for each external definition is consistent with the way it is used.

---

#### Avoiding the problem

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928315/why-does-this-c-program-compile-with-no-errors#comment61417452_36928315), I said:

> This [question] is an argument for making use of headers to ensure that different parts of a program are coherent. If you never declare an external function in a source file but only in headers, and use the headers wherever the relevant symbol (in this case `weird`) is used or defined, then the code would not all compile. You could either have a function or a string, but not both. You'd have a header `weird.h` which contains either `extern char *weird;` or `extern int weird(int *p);` (but not both), and both `main.c` and `weird.c` would include the header, and only one of them would compile successfully.

To which there came the [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928315/why-does-this-c-program-compile-with-no-errors#comment61417997_36928315):

> What could I add to these files to ensure that the error is detected and thrown when `main.c` is compiled?

You'd create 3 source files.  The code shown here is slightly more complicated than you'd normally use because it allows you to use conditional compilation to compile the code with either a function or a variable as the 'external identifier with external linkage' called `weird`.  Normally, you'd select one intended representation for `weird` and only allow that to be exposed.

#### `weird.h`

```
#ifndef WEIRD_H_INCLUDED
#define WEIRD_H_INCLUDED

#ifdef USE_WEIRD_STRING
extern const char *weird;
#else
extern int weird(int *p);
#endif

#endif /* WEIRD_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "weird.h"

int main(void)
{
    int x, *y;

    y = (int *)7;
    x = weird(y);
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    return (0);
}
```

#### `weird.c`

```
#include "weird.h"

#ifdef USE_WEIRD_STRING
const char *weird = "weird";
#else
int weird(int *p)
{
    if (p == 0)
        return 42;
    else
        return 99;
}
#endif
```

#### Valid compilation sequences

```
gcc -c weird.c
gcc -c main.c
gcc -o program weird.o main.o

gcc -o program -DUSE_WEIRD_FUNCTION main.c weird.c
```

Both these work because the code is compiled to use the `weird()` function.  The header, in both cases, ensures that the compilations are consistent.

#### Invalid compilation sequence

```
gcc -c -DUSE_WEIRD_STRING weird.c
gcc -c main.c
gcc -o program weird.o main.o
```

This is basically the same as the setup in the question.  The `weird.c` file is compiled to create a string called `weird`, but the `main.c` code is compiled expecting to use a function `weird()`.  The linker does link the code, but things go disastrously wrong when the function call in `main()` is retargeted to the `"weird"`.  The chances are that the memory where it is stored is not executable and the execution fails because of that.  Otherwise, the string is interpreted as machine code and it probably doesn't do anything meaningful and leads to a crash.  Neither is desirable; neither is guaranteed — this is a result of invoking undefined behaviour.

If you tried to compile `main.c` with `-DUSE_WEIRD_STRING`, the compilation would fail because the header would indicate that `weird` is a `char *` and the code would try to use it as a function.

If you replaced the conditional code in `weird.c` with either the string or the function (unconditionally), then:

- Either the compilation would fail if the file contained the function but `-DUSE_WEIRD_STRING` was set on the command line,
- Or the compilation would fail if the file contained the string but you did not set `-DUSE_WEIRD_STRING`.

Normally, the header would contain an unconditional declaration for `weird`, either as a function or as a pointer (but without any provision for choosing between them at compile time).

The key point is that the header is included in both source files, so unless the conditional compilation flags make a difference, the compiler can check the code in the source files for consistency with the header, and therefore the two object files stand a chance of working together.  If you subvert the checking by setting the compilation flags so that the two source files see different declarations in the header, then you're back to square one.

The header, therefore, declares the interfaces, and the source files are checked to ensure that they adhere to the interface.  The headers are the glue that hold the system together.  Consequently, any function (or variable) that must be accessed outside its source file should be declared in a header (one header only), and that header should be used in the source file where the function (or variable) is defined, and also in every source file that references the function (or variable).  You should not write `extern … weird …;` in a source file; such declarations belong in a header.  All functions (or variables) that are not referenced outside the source file where they're defined should be defined with `static`.  This gives you the maximum chance of spotting problems before you run the program.

You can use GCC to help you.  For functions, you can insist on prototypes being in scope before a (non-`static`) function is referenced or defined (and before a `static` function is referenced — you can simply define a `static` function before it is referenced without a separate prototype).  I use:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration …
```

The `-Wall` and `-Wextra` imply some, but not all, of the other `-W…` options, so that isn't a minimal set.  And not all versions of GCC support both the `-Wold-style-…` options.  But together, these options ensure that functions have a full prototype declaration before the function is used.

Answer (score 1):

Neither file on its own contains any error that would cause a problem with compilation. main.c correctly declares (but doesn't define) a function called `weird` and calls it, and weird.c correctly defines a `char *` named `weird`. After compilation, main.o contains an unresolved reference to `weird` and weird.o contains a definition.

Now, here's the fun part: neither .o file necessarily[*] contains anything about the *type* of `weird`. Just names and addresses. By the time linking is happening, it's too late to say "hey, main expects this to be an `int(*)(int *)` and what you provided is actually a `char *`!" All the linker does is see that the name `weird` is provided by one object and referenced by another, and fits the pieces together like a jigsaw puzzle. In C, it's entirely the programmer's job to make sure that all compilation units that use a given external symbol declare it with compatible types (not necessarily identical; there are intricate rules as to what are "compatible types"). If you don't, the resulting behavior is undefined and probably wrong.

[*]: actually I can think of several cases where the object files *do* contain the types — for example, certain kinds of debugging information, or special .o files for link-time optimization. But as far as I know, even when the type information *does* exist, the linker doesn't use it to warn about things like this.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. So if I wanted this error to be caught when main.c is compiled, would I just need to define weird in main.c?

Comment: to help with compiler diagnosis:  always put a declaration in header files for things that are meant to be public (i.e. visible to all units), and always declare `static` things that are meant to be for this unit onely

Answer (score 1):

<sup>I am taking a Linux point of view. Details could be different on other OSes.</sup>

Of course your latest edit cannot compile, since:

```
char *weird = "weird";
printf(weird); // wrong, remove this line
```

contains a statement (the `printf`) *outside* of any function. So let assume you have removed that line. And `clang-3.7 -Wall -Wextra -c main.c` gives several warnings:

```
main.c:7:9: warning: cast to 'int *' from smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    w = (int *)x;
        ^

main.c:8:9: warning: cast to 'int *' from smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    y = (int *)z;
        ^
main.c:7:16: warning: variable 'x' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    w = (int *)x;
               ^
main.c:6:10: note: initialize the variable 'x' to silence this warning
    int x, *y, z, *w;
         ^
          = 0
main.c:8:16: warning: variable 'z' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    y = (int *)z;
               ^
main.c:6:17: note: initialize the variable 'z' to silence this warning
    int x, *y, z, *w;
                ^
                 = 0
4 warnings generated.
```

Technically, I guess that your example is some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Then the implementation is not supposed to warn you, and [bad things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) can happen (or not!).

You *might* have some warning (but I am not sure) if you enabled *link time optimization* both at compile time *and at link time*, perhaps with

```
gcc -flto -Wall -Wextra -O  -c main.c
gcc -flto -Wall -Wextra -O  -c weird.c
gcc -flto -Wall -Wextra -O  main.o weird.o -o program
```

and you could replace `gcc` by `clang` if you wish to. I guess that asking for optimization (`-O`) is relevant.

Actually I am getting no warnings with `clang-3.7 -flto` but I am getting a warning (at the last link command) with `gcc 6`:

```
 % gcc -flto -O -Wall -Wextra  weird.o main.o -o program  
 main.c:1:5: error: variable ‘weird’ redeclared as function
 int weird(int *);
     ^
 weird.c:3:7: note: previously declared here
 char *weird = "weird";
       ^
 lto1: fatal error: errors during merging of translation units
 compilation terminated.
```

<sup>(I am explaining for GCC which I know well, including some of its internals; for `clang` it should be similar)</sup>

With `-flto` the *compiler*  (e.g. `lto1` with GCC) is also running for linking (so can optimize then, e.g. [inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) calls between [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29)). It is using compiler intermediate representations stored in object files (and these representations contain typing information). Without it, the last command (e.g. your `clang main.o weird.o -o program`) is simply invoking the *linker* `ld` with appropriate options (e.g. for [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) & [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library))

Current [linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) don't keep or handle any [type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) information (pedantically doing some [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure), mostly done by the compiler itself). They just manage *symbols* (that is C identifiers) in some *simple* [symbol table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) and process [*relocations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computing%29). Lack of type information in object files (more precisely, the symbol tables known to the linker) is why [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) is required for C++.

Read more about [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), e.g. [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), the format used by [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) and [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable).

Replace `clang` or `gcc` by `clang -v` or `gcc -v` to understand what is happening (so it would show you the underlying `cc1` or `lto1` or `ld` processes).

As others explained, you really should share a common `#include`-d header file (if the C code is not machine generated but hand written). Some C code generators might avoid generating header files and would generate relevant (and identical) declarations in every generated C file.

Comment: It is frustrating for all concerned that the question has morphed again, currently including code that doesn't compile (`weird.c` is invalid).

Answer (score 0):

when you want to build a executable program, you have to link object.

but now, you just compile the source.

Complier thought 
"ah, you'll compile weird.c later. okay. i'll just compile this one"

Comment: I left out a couple commands by accident in the original question. Please see the updated version!

Comment: It's more a question of "you never mentioned `weird.c` so I won't touch it (any more than you mentioned `impeccable.c`, so I won't touch that, either)".